# How to change the image while clicking button action

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uibutton

I have edit button to edit and delete button to delete action. If i click the edit button i need to display DONE button image. Then user done with delete action again press the DONE i need to show EDIT button with image. Previously i have done with text. How to do with image?

```
 UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"];
 [editButton setBackgroundImage:bg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 //  [editButton setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 -(void)editButtonPressed:(UIButton *)button{



 NSLog(@">>> Entering %s <<<", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

 [tableview setEditing:![tableview isEditing] animated:YES];

 NSString *buttonTitle = ([tableview isEditing]) ? @"Done" : @"Edit";

 [editButton setTitle:buttonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 NSLog(@"<<< Leaving %s >>>", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly the same but with images:

```
UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Edit"];
 [editButton setImage:bg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 //  [editButton setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 -(void)editButtonPressed:(UIButton *)button{



 NSLog(@">>> Entering %s <<<", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

 [tableview setEditing:![tableview isEditing] animated:YES];

 NSString *buttonImageName = ([tableview isEditing]) ? @"Done" : @"Edit";

 [editButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: buttonImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 NSLog(@"<<< Leaving %s >>>", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);


 }
```

Comment: it's working..but when i click the edit button it shows edit & help image, both

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *img=[(UIButton *) sender currentImage];   

if(img == [UIImage imageNamed:@"edit"])
{  
    //If do something
 }
```

Try like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set image for normal state and for selected state. On press toggle button state into selected (table will be in editing mode), on press again toggle button state back into normal.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // ...
    [editButton setImage:normalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [editButton setImage:editmodeImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}

- (void)editButtonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
    tableView.editing = !tableView.editing;
    editButton.selected = tableView.isEditing;
    // ...
}
```